# Combine two separate SQL queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some difficulties with probably a not so difficult SQL task..

I have two queries that I'd like to combine together. Both of them work fine separately, but when I try to combine them together I get different errors such as:

*Error 116: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*

At the same time I do not want to use **EXIST**, but **IN** instead.

Here are the queries:

First:

```
  SELECT C.Id, C.Name, BC.Id AS BCID
    FROM Customers AS C
    RIGHT JOIN Bills AS Bc ON C.Id = BC.Bills_Customer
    RIGHT JOIN Months AS M ON Bc.Month_Bills = M.Id
    WHERE C.Argument = 'KP'
    AND YEAR(bm.Datum) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH(bm.Datum) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ORDER BY C.Name
```

Second:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Account, LastLogin, Licences_Bills 
    FROM Licences 
    WHERE LastLogin > CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,-1,getdate()-2))),dateadd(m,-1,getdate()-1)),106)
    AND LastLogin < CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()),106)
    AND Access = 1 --AND Licences_Bills IN
    ORDER BY Licences_Bills ASC
```

Results from the two queries look like that:

First:

```
 +----------+---------+-----------+
 |  Id      | Name    |   BCID    |  
 +----------+---------+-----------+
 |    1     |  John   |    500    |  
 +----------+---------+-----------+
 |    2     |  Max    |    501    |
 +----------+---------+-----------+
 |    5     |  Foo    |    502    |  
 +----------+---------+-----------+
 |    7     |  Bar    |    503    |
 +----------+---------+-----------+
```

Second:

```
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+
 |  Account |   LastLogin  |  Licences_Bills   |  
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+
 |    abc   |  07.03.2014  |    500            |  
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+
 |    aac   |  13.03.2014  |    500            |
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+
 |    acb   |  28.03.2014  |    504            |  
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+
 |    bca   |  19.03.2014  |    506            |
 +----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Now I'd like to combine these two, so that it displays only rows where the **BCID** from the first query and the **Licences_Bills** from the second query match.

I tried with **IN** and then a nested select, but did not work out. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Clues and/or links to some valuable resources are also appreciated!

**EDIT:**
In the end, I'd like to have the second result list limited to those bills from the first query. This is why I was trying with IN and then nested select. INNER JOIN on the other hand would give me results as the intersection of both tables.

Also, I don't want to see the columns from the first query (as of what happens with join). Just the final result structured as the second query.

Comment: These are separate selects with separate result columns. Do you want to show the first result list limited to those bills that are in the second query? Or do you want to show the second result list limited to those bills that are in the first query? Or a combination of the two results. If the latter is the case then how many records shall be shown for bill #500?

Comment: Incidentally, there are presently ca. 31,000 "LEFT JOINs" on SO (tagged with [mysql]) as compared with ca. 1300 "RIGHT JOINs". Just sayin'

Comment: Thorsten, your right - I forgot to mention that! I'd like to have the second result list limited to those bills from the first query. This is why I was trying with IN and then nested select. INNER JOIN on the other hand would give me results as the intersection of both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the second result list limited to bills you also find in the first query, you will have to Combine them either with IN or with EXISTS. I don't know why this didn't work for you. Maybe just a typo? The following should work. It simply combines the two statements with IN. So in the inner query I only select BC.ID and removed the order by clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Account, LastLogin, Licences_Bills 
FROM Licences 
WHERE LastLogin > CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,-1,getdate()-2))),dateadd(m,-1,getdate()-1)),106)
AND LastLogin < CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()),106)
AND Access = 1 
AND Licences_Bills IN
(
  SELECT BC.Id
  FROM Customers AS C
  RIGHT JOIN Bills AS Bc ON C.Id = BC.Bills_Customer
  RIGHT JOIN Months AS M ON Bc.Month_Bills = M.Id
  WHERE C.Argument = 'KP'
  AND YEAR(bm.Datum) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH(bm.Datum) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
ORDER BY Licences_Bills ASC
```

Comment: Hm, I looked for typos and other similar mistakes, but could not find any. Now I tried this and it worked. I am bit confused, but at the same time relieved I had the correct logic behind it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM

(

SELECT C.Id, C.Name, BC.Id AS BCID
    FROM Customers AS C
    RIGHT JOIN Bills AS Bc ON C.Id = BC.Bills_Customer
    RIGHT JOIN Months AS M ON Bc.Month_Bills = M.Id
    WHERE C.Argument = 'KP'
    AND YEAR(bm.Datum) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH(bm.Datum) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)


) as T1
INNER JOIN

(
SELECT DISTINCT Account, LastLogin, Licences_Bills 
    FROM Licences 
    WHERE LastLogin > CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(dateadd(m,-1,getdate()-2))),dateadd(m,-1,getdate()-1)),106)
    AND LastLogin < CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-(day(getdate())),getdate()),106)
    AND Access = 1

) T2

ON T1.BCID=T2.Licences_Bills
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! That's also an option, but I think in my particular case the marked answer does a better job.

Answer (score 1):

Try with join

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM
(query 1) t1
JOIN (query 2) t2 
ON(t1.BCID = t2.Licences_Bills)
```